# How to add to a windows registry value containing double quotes using robot framework?

Tags: powershell, registry, robotframework, regedit

I want to add a windows registry key at path `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` with key name as `1` and value as `{"pattern":"[*.]","filter":{}}`. Upon running below command, double quotes are getting trimmed in the added entry.

```sh
${rc}    ${out}=    OperatingSystem.Run And Return Rc And Output   powershell Start-Process -Verb runAs -Wait powershell -ArgumentList "{ New-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Google\\Chrome\\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls -Name 1 -Value '{\"pattern\":\"[*.]\",\"filter\":{}}' -PropertyType \"String\" -Force }"
```

[Registry Key after command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqatL.png)

It runs successfully but removes the double quotes in the Registry key.

- Expectation in Registry    : `{"pattern":"[*.]","filter":{}}`
- Observed value in Registry : `{pattern:[*.],filter:{}}`

As observed above, it is removing double quotes surrounding 'pattern' and 'filter' words in the expression. Need help to successfully insert double quotes in registry key.

Comment: I don't know *Robot Framework*, however if I run an analogous nested PowerShell command from `cmd` then I need to use multiple double quotes exponentially. For instance (tripled `"`): `PowerShell -noprofile Write-Output -InputObject '{"""pattern""":"""[*.]""","""filter""":{}}'` returns `{"pattern":"[*.]","filter":{}}` and the same output in elevated _posh_ (tripled `"""`): `Powershell -noprofile Start-Process PowerShell -verb runas -ArgumentList '-noexit', '-noprofile', 'Write-Output -InputObject ''{"""""""""pattern""""""""":"""""""""[*.]""""""""","""""""""filter""""""""":{}}'''`.

Comment: Thanks a Ton man... I have been banging my head for over 5 hours to solve this issue and this worked like a charm.. Really grateful.